# Converting Cartesian equation in form x = y = z into Vector Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is:

> Find the vector equation of the line with Cartesian equation:
>
> $$5x + 1 = -10y - 4 = 2z$$

I know the vector equation of a line is $\textbf{r} × \textbf{v} = \textbf{a} × \textbf{v}$,
where $\textbf{r}$ is the position vector of a point on the line, $\textbf{a}$ is a fixed point on
the line, and $\textbf{v}$ is a direction vector for $\textit{L}$. What I don't get is how the Cartesian equation can give me what I need.

If someone could please explain the process of converting Cartesian into vector form and highlight the link between Cartesian and vector equations  of lines that would be great.

Comment: Put z = t. Now write x and y in terms of t. Now write (x,y,z) as a vector involving t and you are done. If you like, rewrite $(x,y,z) = r_0+te_0$ where $r_0$ and $e_0$ are vectors (which are a point the line goes through and the lines direction respectively).

Comment: @A.Doe Hi, I rolled back the edit because the answers here answer your old question. Your edit would thus invalidate Emilio Novati's answer (Which you accepted). If you have a new question, please ask on a separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

You have:
$$
5x + 1 = -10y - 4 = 2z=t
$$

so:
$$
x=\frac{t-1}{5} \qquad y=\frac{t+4}{-10} \qquad z=\frac{t}{2}
$$

can you find a vector equation from this?

(It has the form $\vec x= t \vec v+ \vec w$)

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the given eqn into a form like

$\frac{x-a}{a'} = \frac{x-b}{b'} = \frac{x-c}{c'}$

You can do that by dividing by some suitable real and some rearranging( please do it yourself).

The rest ia trivial. The eqn of the line in vector form is then
$\vec r = (a,b,c) + \lambda (a',b',c')$ where $(a,b,c) = ai + bj + ck$

How is the vector form achieved from the cartesian form above?

Just take $\frac{x-a}{a'} = \frac{x-b}{b'} = \frac{x-c}{c'} = \lambda$

Then, $x = a + \lambda.a', y = b+ \lambda.b', z = c+ \lambda.c'$

Let $\vec r = (x,y,z)$, then substituting the values of x,y,z e get the required vector eqn.

Comment: Why have you used primes of a, b, c here? The direction vector components have no relation to the position vector and are not derived from it. The notation is often used but IMHOis misleading and I guess if  you copied and pasted it here, it is understandable.  You might consider the use of the word 'trivial' in a teaching situation. This is not a Don to Don discussion, the OP would never have come here if the problem was trivial to them.